# Множественное обьявление

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl2

Вот, что выдает компилятор, все функции и переменные объявлены один раз.

Проект относительно большой, исходники каких именно файлов приложить?

из-за чего именно происходит это? Сижу уже 5й час, пойду попью чаю.. буду через 15 мин, так , что не серчайте, если не сразу дополню.

> obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z8inccordsiiP5cords':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/gGlobal.h:34: multiple definition of`inccords(int, int, cords*)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/gGlobal.h:34: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5Logys4openEPKc':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:36: multiple definition of`Logys::open(char const*)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:36: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5Logys4readB5cxx11Ei':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:41: multiple definition of`Logys::readabi:cxx11'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:41: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5Logys5writeEPKc':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:57: multiple definition of`Logys::write(char const*)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:57: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5Logys5clearEv':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:69: multiple definition of`Logys::clear()'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:69: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5Logys4sizeEv':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:80: multiple definition of`Logys::size()'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/Logs/cLog.h:80: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5Click4bornEPiS0_':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:39: multiple definition of`Click::born(int*, int*)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:39: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4MenuC2Ev':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:102: multiple definition of`Menu::Menu()'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:102: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4MenuC2Ev':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:102: multiple definition of`Menu::Menu()'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:102: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4Menu5setupEiP10SDL_WindowP12SDL_RendererP5ModelP12Menu_Handler':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:111: multiple definition of`Menu::setup(int, SDL_Window*, SDL_Renderer*, Model*, Menu_Handler*)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:111: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4Menu10add_buttonEiiiii':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:120: multiple definition of`Menu::add_button(int, int, int, int, int)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:120: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4Menu3runEb':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:129: multiple definition of`Menu::run(bool)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:129: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4Menu6inputsEv':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:140: multiple definition of`Menu::inputs()'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:140: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4Menu7outputsEv':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:161: multiple definition of`Menu::outputs()'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:161: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4Menu14connect_outputE6output':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:179: multiple definition of`Menu::connect_output(output)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:179: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN4Menu13connect_inputE5input':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:180: multiple definition of`Menu::connect_input(input)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu.h:180: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN12Menu_Handler5setupEP12SDL_RendererP10SDL_WindowP5Model':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:40: multiple definition of`Menu_Handler::setup(SDL_Renderer*, SDL_Window*, Model*)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:40: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN12Menu_Handler9seek_menuEi':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:45: multiple definition of`Menu_Handler::seek_menu(int)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:45: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN12Menu_Handler10check_runsEv':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:57: multiple definition of`Menu_Handler::check_runs()'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:57: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z15global_redirectP12Menu_HandleriiP5Model':
>   C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:69: multiple definition of`global_redirect(Menu_Handler*, int, int, Model*)'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/programs/FMV5/cMenu_Handler.h:69: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZSt19__iterator_categoryIPcENSt15iterator_traitsIT_E17iterator_categoryERKS2_':
>   C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:302: multiple definition of`renderer'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:302: first defined here
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZSt19__iterator_categoryIPcENSt15iterator_traitsIT_E17iterator_categoryERKS2_':
>   C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:303: multiple definition of`window'
>   obj\Debug\input\cppButton.o:C:/c++/codeblocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:303: first defined here
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Паучье чутье мне подсказывает, что вы определили функции в хедерах, но забыли поставить на них `inline`.

Comment: *"исходники каких именно файлов приложить?"* См. [mcve].

Comment: благодарю за наводку и ссылку, дополню

Comment: и да, верно, функции определены в хедерах, только учу язык

Comment: Ну тогда о каком "определены один раз" вы ведёте речь? Пять раз включили хедер - получили пять определений. Отсюда и ошибки.

Comment: Скорее всего include guard или pragma once решит проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Вы определили ваши функции в хедерах.

Даже если у вас стоят **include guard** или **pragma once**, это врятли решит проблему. Дело в том, что у вас есть несколько единиц трансляции, и каждая функция, определённая в хедере, оказывается в каждой единице трансляции, где был сделан соответствующий include (это очень примитивное объяснение, но я просто не хочу слишком детально на нём останавливаться).

Решить проблему можно тремя способами.

1. Перенести все определения функция в cpp-файлы. Это самый правильный способ, не подойдёт, если ваши функции шаблонные (но для шаблонных у вас не должно было возникнуть описанной в вопросе ошибки).
2. Добавить всем функциям спецификатор inline, например:

   ```
   inline void add_button(int, int, int, int, int) {/*...*/}
   ```

   Это поможет, но лучше так не делать.
3. Сделать все функции шаблонными (но это уже совсем плохо, делать шаблоном только ради того, чтобы определить в хедере, **крайне не рекомендую так поступать**).

Суммируя всё вышесказанное, самое правильное решение - перенести все реализации в cpp-файл (1й способ). Если нужно очень быстро поэкспериментировать - можно воспользоваться вторым методом (но потом всё равно перенести реализации).